# How to Set Logon User Rights with the Ntrights.exe in windows 10(64 bit)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, 64-bit

I need to know whether ntrights.exe 64 bit version exists?

If not, which is the 64 bit equivalent of ntrights.exe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**What is an equivalent for ntrights.exe on Windows 10?**

Set and Check User Rights Assignment via Powershell
You can add, remove, and check User Rights Assignment (remotely / locally) with the following Powershell scripts.

Read the blakedrumm [page for detailed instructions, and download the script](https://blakedrumm.com/blog/set-and-check-user-rights-assignment/).

I just tested it successfully on Windows 2022 Standard.

Comment: This look really useful but all of the links are broken.