# How to add Virtual Machines to Log on as a service Properties in command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, hyper-v, gpedit

Following [this question](https://superuser.com/a/1719154/588662), I have found [this page](https://kimconnect.com/hyper-v-logon-failure-the-user-has-no-been-granted-the-requested-logon-type-at-this-computer-0x80070569/) instructing to add "Virtual Machines" in `Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Log on as a service`. However, the "Add User or Group" button is grayed out for me, even if I open the `gpedit.msc` as an admin:

[image]

Now I was wondering if there is a way to add the above item through the command line (i.e., PowerShell and/or cmd).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40356586/4999991) mentioned `LGPO.exe` tool and [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1107642/588662) provides a PS script as an alternative to `ntrights.exe` for newer versions of Windows OS. Sadly I don't know if/how either of those work.